# Find a specific Text in WebPage via Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

how is it possible for me to let Selenium search for a specific Line in the Code of a Website?

I am searching for the Line i attached in the photo.

Thanks in advance!

[Image Info Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeVWU.png)

Comment: Select that line and copy full xpath. Then use `driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"))` to get that element

Comment: Thanks! Problem is, i want to chek the whole List in this class for the word "Fehler" thats my main problem :)

Comment: so you are searching for the word instead of the specific line?

Comment: for the word "Fehler" yes !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the inner text of an element by either:

1. `inner_text = element.get_attribute('innerText')`;
2. `inner_text = element.text`;

Therefore, you can scan all those divs with the condition of `inner_text == "Fehler"`.

Since the ids follow a pattern, here's how you can scan the divs and select the element:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def id_value(index):
    return f"cdk-describe-message-{index}"


def find_innertext(driver, url, text, N):
    driver.get(url)
    for idx in range(N):
        element = driver.find_elements(By.ID, id_value(idx))
        if element.text == text:
            return element


def main():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    url = "https://...."
    target = "Fehler"
    number_of_divs = 40
    return find_innertext(driver, url, target, number_of_divs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    element = main()
```

Notes:

- you have to know the number of divs elements there are in advance;
- consider using [waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is what i got so far:

```
def main():


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

smalogin = "https://172.16.63.100/webui/login"


driver.get(smalogin)

driver.implicitly_wait(100)

email = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username")

email.send_keys('user')

password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password")

password.send_keys('pass')

submit = driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="login"]/button')

submit.click()

monitoring = driver.find_element(By.ID,"ennexos-element-monitoring")

monitoring.click()

statusliste = driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="cdk-accordion-child-0"]/div/div/sma-feature-board-slot[1]/sma-navigation-link')

statusliste.click()


time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```